# Python numpy XOR return NotImplemented

Tags: python, numpy

It is OK to use numpy.logical_xor in the terminal:

```
>>> numpy.logical_xor(numpy.array([0,2,0,59,1]), numpy.array([0,0,0,0,0]))
    array([False,  True, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

But in IDE:

```
loan_Y_default = np.logical_xor( loan_Y, np.zeros(loan_Y.shape))
```

"loan_Y_default" is printed as "NotImplemented". "loan_Y" has a shape [100, 1]

What is going on here?

Comment: What is the dtype of `loan_Y`?

Comment: @ali_m the dtype is int

Comment: I can't reproduce this for any of numpy's int dtypes (`np.{u}int{8, 16, 32, 64}`). Which version of numpy are you using?

Comment: @ali_m OPh, I guess the dtype is string. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a ndarray of strings, and that should return "NotImplemented":

```
In [1001]: a=np.array(['1', '2'])

In [1002]: np.logical_xor(a, np.zeros(a.shape))
Out[1002]: NotImplemented
```

what you need to do is transform the strings to numbers first:

```
In [1005]: a=a.astype(float)

In [1006]: a
Out[1006]: array([ 1.,  2.])

In [1007]: np.logical_xor(a, np.zeros(a.shape))
Out[1007]: array([ True,  True], dtype=bool)
```